# Configure network from other computer

Tags: networking, bash, powershell, vpn

I'm doing a project from my last year of System Administration and Networks (Technical College in Spain) and I need help with this situation:

[image: Schema from the project]

A Client (from other network and connected to the web via VPN) will access a web hosted by the DMZ Server with Apache which have a list of network configurations for O1 (configurable host), after the client has selected all the configurations for O1 the web will export all the configurations to an JSON file and send it to Server, to translate it to an network configuration script (Bash or PowerShell) and apply that configuration to O1.

Is there any way the Server could configure O1 automatically without accepting or touching nothing in that machine? I would like to configure: Interface configuration (Name of interface, IP, Netmask, DNS...) and Hostname.

So far, I've only completed the outline and learned the theory. I wish someone could help me with this, thanks for reading!

---

Edit made for responding questions.

1. The first machine can only see the Web, all the scripts, administration, etc will be hidden, that's why I'm saying that I want to avoid as much as possible making things manually in O1.
2. I named it "Configurable Host" for nothing, its just for explain it would be the machine in which the changes will occur.
3. I don't want to configure the interface that connects the Server with O1, if I do that I guess that it will disconnect. I want to configure the other interfaces. I guess for connecting O1 with Server I need to previously make the interfaces

Searching a lot I saw tools for configurations like Ansible, Chef or Puppet, If someone used one of this three or other alternative could comment in this question please!

Comment: +1 for being upfront that's it is an assignment and for not asking for the complete answer

Comment: Thanks for the +1 Rohit Gupta! It helps a lot so more people can reach this.

Comment: `Is there any way the Server could configure O1 automatically without accepting or touching nothing in that machine?` What does this even mean? What was the thing in mind that that you were trying to avoid "accepting" / "touching"? And by configuring network, do you mean to configure the very same interface that connects "O1" to "Server"? Doesn't sound a very good idea if that's the case (and doesn't make much sense to me if you mean like the interface wasn't configured at all in the initial setup, since that would mean "O1" is not exactly connected to "Server" / their LAN).

Comment: Btw IMHO you should give us some brief idea what this "project" is about (like, what was the point to have such a "configurable" host; to be frank I have no idea what "configurable host" means; maybe it's just me though)

Comment: Hello Tom Yan, thanks for apporting in the question, I'll try to explain the best that I can.

Comment: @MatiasGdo Please do not add information / clarifications in comments. Rather [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1769297/edit) your question accordingly. This way all the relevant info is readily available for the community members. I'd also suggest deleting these comments just to avoid confusing the matter.

Comment: If you want to configure the network of a computer without 'touching' the system, then the system will need to get the information itself. DHCP comes to mind as the most obvious candidate.If you want to configure the network of a computer without 'touching' the system, then the system will need to get the information itself. DHCP comes to mind as the most obvious candidate.

Comment: Assign the network configuration from server using DHCP? Its a good idea!